# How to access Ubuntu 14.04 server remotely using GUI

Tags: server, graphics, lightdm, remote-desktop, xserver

I have installed Xserver using these commands

```
sudo apt-get install xauth
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

Even I have installed nautilus.
I have installed xming on my windows 10 mcahine.
Now when using putting and xming and running the command startx I am getting a graphical window, which doesn't look good and too slow.
What I read is that xming uses the client graphics driver opnegl and not server driver and it should be quite fast.
What I am missing here.
Do I need to install lightdm or GDM on ubuntu.

Another question is if I install

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Will the server boot into graphical environment, which I don't want. I just want to access the remote ubuntu 14.04 server graphically and when session is terminated it just remains as a headless server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try x2go. It's basically allows you to run remote X session:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X2Go